# ASP.NET GridView passing parameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but no value is being returned on my grid.

I have the following in my .aspx.cs  file:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        SqlDS1.SelectParameters.Add("@ID", "6");    
  }
```

I have the following in my .aspx file

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LisSQL %>"                
    SelectCommand="select RemediationID, RemediationDate, RemediationUser, RemediationAction from VAPHS_Remediation WHERE ID = @ID">
     <SelectParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDS1" Width="1200px" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowSorting="True">
       <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemediationID"  HeaderText="RemediationID"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemediationDate"  HeaderText="RemediationDate"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemediationUser"  HeaderText="RemediationUser"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RemediationAction"  HeaderText="RemediationAction"/>             
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Nothing gets returned although there is a record for ID = 6

Comment: Does `select RemediationID, RemediationDate, RemediationUser, RemediationAction from VAPHS_Remediation WHERE ID=6` return anything if you query in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, it does return a value. Just not sure why it doesn't in the above coding though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `DefaultValue` instead of add.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlDS1.SelectParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = "6";
}
```

You already have declarative parameter already; if you use `Add` parameter, it'll add another duplicate one.